# Zip script to enforce a particular zipped directory structure

Tags: bash, zip

So I have the following project directory structure:

```
myapp/
  package/
    <PACKAGE_CONTENTS>
    (this is a very deeply nested directory structure under here
     with many files and subdirs)
  fizz/
    a.txt
    b.jpg
    c.pdf
    <lots more files and subdirs here>
  buzz/
    d.json
    e.xml
    <lots more files and subdirs here>
  foobaz/
    f.yml
    g.py
    <lots more files and subdirs here>
  flimflam.yarp
```

What I need (end result) is a ZIP file that, if I were to unzip it, would have the following directory structure:

```
flimflam.yarp
<PACKAGE_CONTENTS>
fizz/
  a.txt
  b.jpg
  c.pdf
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
buzz/
  d.json
  e.xml
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
foobaz/
  f.yml
  g.py
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
```

Where `<PACKAGE_CONTENTS>` is **everything** inside the `myapp/package/` directory, preserved *exactly* as it appears in `myapp/package/`, but **not** under `myapp/package/`. Hence if the only thing inside `myapp/package/` was a file called `bears.boop`, then the unzipped ZIP file would produce:

```
flimflam.yarp
bears.boop
fizz/
  a.txt
  b.jpg
  c.pdf
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
buzz/
  d.json
  e.xml
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
foobaz/
  f.yml
  g.py
  <lots more files and subdirs here>
```

But again, `myapp/package/` is a very large directory with many levels of files and subdirs.

So far I have worked out:

```
cd package
zip -r ../myapp.zip .
cd ..
zip -g myapp.zip flimflam.yarp
```

And this works, when I unzip `myapp.zip` I get:

```
flimflam.yarp
<PACKAGE_CONTENTS>
```

So far so good. But now I need to include the `fizz`, `buzz` and `foobaz` directories, and in such a way that their directory structure is perfectly preserved from the root.. **What zip command and/or bash scripting can I leverage here to recursively crawl these other directories and place them in the ZIP as I need them to be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try passing all contents of `myapp` except `package` to the second `zip` command like so:

```
cd package
zip -r ../myapp.zip .
cd ..
shopt -s extglob
zip -g -r myapp.zip !(package)
```